# How can I run a Flutter Linux desktop application in full screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I need to run a Flutter Linux application in full screen, how can this be achieved? I've looked at the WindowUtils plugin but it only supports desktop embedding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On Linux, Flutter runs above GTK, so you may edit the file **linux/my_application.cc**
and after the line:

```
gtk_window_set_default_size(window, 1280, 720);
```

Insert the following line:

```
gtk_window_fullscreen(GTK_WINDOW(window));
```

Comment: I would not replace that line, rather add that line below it so there is a default size when you exit fullscreen mode (F11 often works). Otherwise you get a fairly odd small window.

Comment: Thank you! this worked! How could gtk is able to do this and ubuntu isn't? Does gtk use X11 directly to make this happen? Just trying to figure out how it works